# Freeform output styling

Tags: templating, plugin-freeform

When rendering the output of a single Star Rating field using the default Flexbox form, the output creates its own styling, overriding what I put in the element it's in... and adds a "float: left" pushing the star rating to the left. What I want is for it to be centered like the other content in the div. I'm fine with the default styling of the form before submitting, but why is it floating this content left when I'm just calling that one field in the "thanks" page displayed after they submit?

```
<div id="custom-content">   
<h1>Thank you for your feedback!</h1>
{% set submission = craft.freeform.submissions({
  form: 'giveFeedback',
}).one() %}
<br />
<br />
    <p>
        We have received your submission.
    </p>
    <br />
     <p>       {% if submission %}
     {{ submission.starRating.renderInput()}}
     {% endif %} </p>
</div>
```